# Want to show a list of cards with text which is coming from textfield on a screen when the send button is pressed

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, bloc

I want to show a card with text containing in it. The text value is coming from the TextField input and it should instantly display the values on a new Card whenever the button is pressed.

I have created two separate files :
**notestream.dart** to display the cards, and **notetextfield.dart** to send the value to the database

#### notetextfield.dart

**TextField**

```
 TextField(
    controller: _textEditingController,
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
    onChanged: (value) {
    messageText = value;
    noteText = value;
  },
            ......
            ......
  ),
```

**onPressed**

```
 IconButton(
       onPressed: () {
       _textEditingController.clear();
       /Implement send functionality.
       final newNote = Note(noteText: noteText);

       if (newNote.noteText.isNotEmpty) {
       /*Create new Note object and make sure
        the Note textis not empty,
        because what's the point of saving empty
        Note
       */
       noteBloc.addNote(newNote);
       noteBloc.getNotes();
   }
  },
```

#### notestream.dart

The card will be generate with the help of a separate file containing code for the cards.

```
final NoteBloc noteBloc = NoteBloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: noteBloc.notes,
      builder: (
                BuildContext context, 
                AsyncSnapshot<List<Note>>snapshot
               ) {

        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          /*Also handles whenever there's stream
          but returned returned 0 records of Note from DB.
          If that the case show user that you have empty Notes
         */
          return snapshot.data.length != 0
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, itemPosition) {
                    Note note = snapshot.data[itemPosition];
                    return NoteCard(
                      noteText: note.noteText,
                      noteImagePath: note.noteImagePath,
                    );
                  })
```

#### bloc.dart

```
class NoteBloc {
  //Get instance of the Repository
  final _noteRepository = NoteRepository();

  final _noteController = StreamController<List<Note>>.broadcast();

  get notes => _noteController.stream;

  NoteBloc() {
    getNotes();
  }

  getNotes({String query}) async {
    //sink is a way of adding data reactively to the stream
    //by registering a new event
    _noteController.sink.add(await _noteRepository.getAllNotes(query: 
 query));
  }

  addNote(Note note) async {
    await _noteRepository.insertNote(note);
    getNotes();
  }

  updateTodo(Note note) async {
    await _noteRepository.updateNote(note);
    getNotes();
  }

  dispose() {
    _noteController.close();
  }
}
```

Whenever I am pressing the onPressed button from the **notetextfield.dart** file the list of cards are not getting displayed on the screen.

Comment: what is exactly your doubt?

Comment: updated the last part of question.

Comment: can you add the bloc class?

Comment: @haroldolivieri added

Comment: the bloc instance used inside onPressed is the same instance used on notestream.dart?

Comment: No created a seperate noteBloc instance for it... I don't know how to share a single noteBloc Instance between the 2 files and later dispose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using a different instance of `NoteBloc` on each file, you should have one single source of truth.

Try using the [provider library](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) to provide instances on parent and consume it on its children.

you would provide the bloc on the parent Widget like this

```
Provider<NoteBloc>(
  builder: (context) => NoteBloc(noteRepository: NoteRepository()),
  dispose: (context, value) => value.dispose()
  child: ParentWidget(),
)
```

and you can consume it on any child like this

```dart
final bloc = Provider.of<NoteBloc>(BuildContext context)
```

or this if you prefer to wrap the Widget

```dart
Consumer<NoteBloc>(
    builder: (context, bloc, _) => ChildWidget()
```